# ListView passing touch events to widget under it

Tags: flutter

I have a sidebar which is a `ListView`. This `ListView` contains multiple `ExpansionTile` with `ListTile`. In the image below, in the red portion of the side menu, all taps are being transferred to the `YoutubePlayerIFrame` under it. The library I used for the youtube video player is: `youtube_player_iframe`. The red area, I cannot expand the `ExpansionTile`. The green portion has no problems.

[image]

Below is the code of the side menu:

```
    class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideMenu({
    Key? key,
    required index,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MenuController>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) {
      return Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 210.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: DrawerHeader(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Image.asset("assets/images/psu_logo.png",)
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    Text("Title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                    Text("Subtitle", textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Home",
              index: 0,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 0,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_home.png",
              press: () {
                //Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(0, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 1",
              index: 1,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 1,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_1.png",
              press: () {
                // Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(1, 0);
                print(provider.getCurrentDrawer);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 2",
              index: 2,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 2,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_2.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(2, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 3",
              index: 3,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 3,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_3.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(3, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 4",
              index: 4,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 4,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_4.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(4, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 5",
              index: 5,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 5,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_5.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(5, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 6",
              index: 6,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 6,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_6.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(6, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 7",
              index: 7,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 7,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_7.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(7, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 8",
              index: 8,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 8,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_8.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(8, 0);
              },
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Area 9",
              index: 9,
              submenu: provider.getCurrentSubmenu,
              selected: provider.getCurrentDrawer == 9,
              svgSrc: "assets/images/menu_9.png",
              press: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                provider.updateMenu(9, 0);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  DrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    // For selecting those three line once press "Command+D"
    required this.title,
    required this.svgSrc,
    required this.press,
    required this.selected,
    required this.index,
    required this.submenu,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool selected;
  final int index;
  final int submenu;
  final String title, svgSrc;
  final VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return index == 0 ? ListTile(
      selected: selected,
      onTap: press,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      leading: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage(svgSrc),
        color: selected ? Color(0xFFffdf00) : Colors.white54,
        size: 20,
      ),
      title: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.8, 0),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.white54),
        ),
      ),
    ) : ExpansionTile(
      leading: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage(svgSrc),
        color: selected ? Color(0xFFffdf00) : Colors.white54,
        size: 18,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.white54),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          selected: (context.read<MenuController>().getCurrentDrawer == index && submenu == 0),
          onTap: (){
            context.read<MenuController>().updateMenu(index, 0);
            print("${index}, ${0}");
          },
          horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
            child: Text('Area ${index} - Home',
              style: TextStyle(color: (context.read<MenuController>().getCurrentDrawer == index && submenu == 0) ? Colors.white : Colors.white54),),
          ),

        ),
        for (int i=0; i<num_params[index]; i++)
          ListTile(
            selected: context.read<MenuController>().getCurrentDrawer == index && submenu == (i+1),
            onTap: (){
              context.read<MenuController>().updateMenu(index, i+1);
              print("${index}, ${i+1}");
            },
            horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
              child: Text('Parameter ${parameters[i]}',
                style: TextStyle(color: (context.read<MenuController>().getCurrentDrawer == index && submenu == (i+1)) ? Colors.white : Colors.white54),),
            ),

          ),
      ],
    );
  }
  List<int> num_params = [0, 10, 5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 7, 4, 4];
  List<String> parameters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your ListView inside a Container and get the Container a color.

Comment: not working. I already wrapped it but the taps are still passed to the youtube video under it.